# How to create shipment programmatically in magento 2 via script

Tags: magento2

How to create shipment programmatically in magento 2 via script
I have order id & i want to generate shipment 
can someone provide direct script to run from root folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Check this article to: [Programmatically Create Shipment In MSI](https://mageprince.com/blog/how-to-create-shipment-programmatically-with-msi-magento-2/)**

I used this script in many live projects and it's working without any issue. You can use orderId or increment id in this script.

```
<?php

use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include('app/bootstrap.php');

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orderInterface = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface');


//Use this if you have orderId
//$orderId = "100"; //Order Id
//$order = $orderInterface->load($orderId);
 
$incrementId = "000000165"; //Increment Id
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')
        ->loadByAttribute('increment_id', $incrementId);

if ($order->canShip()) {
    // Initialize the order shipment object
    $convertOrder = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Convert\Order');
    $shipment = $convertOrder->toShipment($order);
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ($order->getAllItems() AS $orderItem) {
        // Check if order item has qty to ship or is virtual
        if (! $orderItem->getQtyToShip() || $orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
            continue;
        }
        $qtyShipped = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();
        // Create shipment item with qty
        $shipmentItem = $convertOrder->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem)->setQty($qtyShipped);
        // Add shipment item to shipment
        $shipment->addItem($shipmentItem);
    }

    // Register shipment
    $shipment->register();
    $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

    try {
        // Save created shipment and order
        $shipment->save();
        $shipment->getOrder()->save();

        // Send email
        //$objectManager->create('Magento\Shipping\Model\ShipmentNotifier')
        //    ->notify($shipment);
        //$shipment->save();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
       echo "Shipment Not Created". $e->getMessage(); exit;
    }

    echo "Shipment Succesfully Generated for order: #".$incrementId;
} else {
    echo "Shipment Not Created Becuase It's already created or something went wrong";
}
```

Comment: Hello Prince. Do you know about how to manage different list.phtml in each category?

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to create shipment programatically.

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

/**
 * If your external file is in root folder
 */
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

/**
 * If your external file is NOT in root folder
 * Let's suppose, your file is inside a folder named 'xyz'
 *
 * And, let's suppose, your root directory path is
 * /var/www/html/magento2
 */
// $rootDirectoryPath = '/var/www/html/magento2';
// require $rootDirectoryPath . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$params = $_SERVER;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$_objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();   

$order = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')
    ->loadByAttribute('increment_id', '000000001');

// Check if order can be shipped or has already shipped
if (! $order->canShip()) {
    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __('You can\'t create an shipment.')
                );
}

// Initialize the order shipment object
$convertOrder = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Convert\Order');
$shipment = $convertOrder->toShipment($order);

// Loop through order items
foreach ($order->getAllItems() AS $orderItem) {
    // Check if order item has qty to ship or is virtual
    if (! $orderItem->getQtyToShip() || $orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
        continue;
    }

    $qtyShipped = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();

    // Create shipment item with qty
    $shipmentItem = $convertOrder->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem)->setQty($qtyShipped);

    // Add shipment item to shipment
    $shipment->addItem($shipmentItem);
}

// Register shipment
$shipment->register();

$shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

try {
    // Save created shipment and order
    $shipment->save();
    $shipment->getOrder()->save();

    // Send email
    $_objectManager->create('Magento\Shipping\Model\ShipmentNotifier')
        ->notify($shipment);

    $shipment->save();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __($e->getMessage())
                );
}
```

Comment: You can put above file in root directory.

Comment: error : ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: You can't create an shipment. in /var/www/magento2/shipment.php on line 30
( ! ) Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: You can't create an shipment. in /var/www/magento2/shipment.php on line 30

Comment: That order may be already shipped. Can you check with another order id ?

Comment: @Kishan how do I add tracking number before save the shipment? (one tracking per order)